# How to highlight a particular cell that has duplicate value in Sudoku grid?

Tags: jquery

I have a sudoku grid with 81 cells whose `id` values are from `00` to `88`, all of which are text boxes. I have written the following `jQuery` code which only alerts that a duplicate value has been found in the current row or in the current column or current `3 * 3` subGrid. How to highlight or blink the particular cell only where duplicate value is found in row and/or column and/or subGrid? Also the highlighted color or blinking effect should be nullified when the user removes the newly inserted number. Thanks in advance.

```
$('table tr td input').on({
    "input": function () {
        var cellValue = $(this).val();
        var cellName = $(this).attr('name');
        var row = parseInt(cellName.substring(0, 1));
        var col = parseInt(cellName.substring(1, 2));
        var id;
        var value;

        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i != col) {
                id = row + "" + i;
                value = document.getElementById(id).value;
                if (value == cellValue && cellValue.length > 0) {
                    alert("Duplicate Value is Found");
                }
            }
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (j != row) {
                id = j + "" + col;
                value = document.getElementById(id).value;
                if (value == cellValue && cellValue.length > 0) {
                    alert("Duplicate Value is Found");
                }
            }
        }

        var gridRow = row - (row % 3);
        var gridColumn = col - (col % 3);
        for (var r = gridRow; r < gridRow + 3; ++r) {
            for (var c = gridColumn; c < gridColumn + 3; ++c) {
                if (r != row || c != col) {
                    id = r + "" + c;
                    value = document.getElementById(id).value;
                    if (value == cellValue && cellValue.length > 0) {
                        alert("Duplicate Value is Found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this you can use css() of jquery , for example

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    if (i != col) {
                        id = row + "" + i;
                        value = document.getElementById(id).value;
                        if (value == cellValue && cellValue.length > 0) {
                            $('#'+id).css('background-color','red');//for example
                        } else {
                            $('#'+id).css('background-color','inherit');//for example
                          }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you. But the highlighted color has to be removed when the player removes the newly entered number. How to do it?

Comment: just in else you can assign it to NONE again , as i have edited

Comment: try using css('background-color','inherit'); or .css('background-color','');